# android: How to play YouTube video on emulator

Tags: android, android-video-player

Could someone help me in

1.Is this possible to play video from YouTube on emulator using YouTube video link (like:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T1Wgp3mLa_E) ? If not, then why? 
2.If yes then how ?

I tried to play YouTube video using VideoView but got

`"Command PLAYER_INIT completed with an error or info PVMFErrCorrupt"` message through logcat command.

Comment: I'm putting my answer here, because I don't really know, but it's probably something like startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T1Wgp3mLa_E"));

Comment: You tried playing a YouTube video in a `VideoView`? That doesn't sound like it would work at all, emulator or real device. If you're simply trying to show a YouTube video full screen in your app, use `ACTION_VIEW` on the youtube.com URL. The user will need the YouTube app installed for it to work.

Comment: Actually I want to make my own YouTube app to play YouTube Video.

Comment: whatever you used YouTube will provide the mobile version site for all Videos. it will automatically redirect to the phone's default player. Dont worry to do that. one my friend had done it on Iphone. i didnt checked it in android. hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

Video not play on emulator.

but it might be possible on device
try this..

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this); 
String htmlString = "<html> <body> <embed src=\"youtube link\"; type=application/x-shockwave-flash width="+widthOfDevice+" height="+heightOfDevice+"> </embed> </body> </html>"; 
webview.loadData(htmlString ,"text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: It will not worked for me on device also .Is device requires flash player  or something else??